# Erro ao logar em aplicações

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Bem, o cenário é o seguinte:

Tenho **2 aplicações** `ASP.NET MVC` em um mesmo projeto, que estão utilizando um `Dominio` em comum. Chamarei de `MVC1`  e `MVC2` pra ficar melhor na exemplificação.

Instalei o `Identity`, `EntityFramework` no `dominio`, e **QUASE** tudo até então parece funcionar normalmente.

No `MVC1`logo normalmente, e se acesso o sistema do `MVC2` me mostra que estou logado. Consigo efetuar logoff dentre outras funcionalidades. O que me faz pensar que está tudo OK.

Agora vamos lá...

O Unico problema que tive foi de logar no projeto `MVC2`. Me retorna o erro:

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'. Referência de objeto não definida
>   para uma instância de um objeto. Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem
>   tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o
>   rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde
>   foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.NullReferenceException: Referência de
>   objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
>
> Erro de Origem:
>
> Linha 74:             // This doesn't count login failures towards
>   account lockout Linha 75:             // To enable password failures
>   to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
>
> Linha 76:var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email,
>   model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
>
> Linha 77:
>   switch (result) Linha 78:

**Código do `controller`:**

```
 [HttpPost]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
   {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Porém, *Debugando*, coloquei um `BreakPoint` na linha 76 do `controller` que é a qual me gera o erro, os campos necessários para o login estão preenchidos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E vi que logando através do `MVC1`(o que logo normalmente sem o erro) ele não entra neste método do `controller`. Já o `MVC2` entra e me retorna o erro citado acima.

**Como resolvo este problema ?**

Comment: Como está `model`, `model.Email`, `model.Password` e `model.RememberMe`?

Comment: Sim. Inseri uma imagem. os campos chegam preenchidos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente faltou a injeção de dependência. Verifique em seu arquivo `Startup.Auth.cs` se `SignInManager` está sendo instanciando corretamente:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```